# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x),p)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]/(f(x))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $p$ be a prime. Is it true that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x),p)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]/(f(x))$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. One way to prove this is to give an isomorphism. Can you think of a map between the two rings that would do the trick? Note that in general for a commutative ring $R$ with ideals $I,J\lhd R$ it is true that $(R/I)/J\cong R/(I+J)\cong(R/J)/I$. Try constructing the isomorphisms.

Answer (score 2):

Useful trick to prove isomorphisms $A/B\cong C/D$: find some natural auxiliar epimorphism $g:A\longrightarrow C/D$ with $\ker g=B$.

Comment: This is the first isomorphism theorem. Not really a trick, but an absolute basic for algebra.

Comment: The trick is  the whole process: find ... and use the first isomorphism theorem.